# Why is my javascript object empty after constructing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I use Knockout.js, and I have an object called `letter` in my script. That code looks as follows:

```
function letter(filePath, imagePath, countryId) {
    self.filePath = filePath;
    self.imagePath = imagePath;
    self.countryId = countryId;
}
```

Then, another place in my code, the following snippet runs:

```
  var uploadedLetter = new letter(data.key,'',59);
  viewModel.letters.push(uploadedLetter);
```

I know that my data.key is a normal string value.

My viewModel code is like this:

```
var SendWindowedLetterViewModel = function(formSelector, data) {
    var self = this;
    self.letters = ko.observableArray([]);
}
```

Applying bindings on my view:

```
   var createLetterData = {
    };

    var viewModel = new SendWindowedLetterViewModel('#sendLetterForm', createLetterData);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('sendLetterForm'));
```

However, when I look in FireBug after this line has been run, I have the following output:

[image]

And I cannot access any of my properties, and if I lookup the object in FireBug, it seems to be 100% empty.

Probably the most simple question ever asked on StackOverflow, but what am I overlooking here?

Comment: @Tanner , yeah I just added that code as well :-)

Comment: yeah, first check, deleted comment after your update

Comment: Your code is incorrect in the question. You are missing the `var self = this;` in your letter function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `letter`, you use `self.filePath = filePath`.
But `self` isn't defined anywhere in its scope.

So you either do

```
function letter(filePath, imagePath, countryId) {
    var self = this;
    self.filePath = filePath;
    self.imagePath = imagePath;
    self.countryId = countryId;
}
```

or directly

```
function letter(filePath, imagePath, countryId) {
    this.filePath = filePath;
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
    this.countryId = countryId;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that solved my issue :-) Thanks a lot for pointing out that very obvious mistake

Comment: was going to post the answer but too slow, here's a working fiddle, that I created for what it's worth: http://jsfiddle.net/ht6Gt/